# Why can't I step through library code when debugging a web project in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Spring MVC web application where the majority of the code I am interested in sits in two Maven projects - one being the war project and another being a jar project on which the war depends. They also share the same parent pom though that is probably irrelevant for this question.

When I try to debug my web project I can't step into any of the code from the jar. I've checked Windows->Debugging->Sources and the jar project's source directory is present there. Both projects are open. Does Netbeans 7.0 not support stepping through a web project's dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your library manager screen, in your sources tab, have you provided the location of the source folder.[http://wiki.netbeans.org/AttachSourceToLibrary.](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AttachSourceToLibrary)

When you are stepping in to class files ( that netbeans could not find source far), there usually is a prompt from Netbeans asking if you want to associate a src with this corresponding file. Either way, I have managed to step into dependent projects using Netbeans.

Comment: Your solution works but it's pretty kludgy. I had to add a new library with the path to my jar and source jar in my local Maven repository. Unfortunately that means I'll have to update that path whenever the artifact version is incremented. Netbeans should really do this automatically since it is already handling my "libraries" via Maven.

Comment: Thanks for making me look up the word Kludgy :). I agree it is Kludgy. If your system  is in active development and you foresee very volatile artifact version numbers, I will suggest you look inside the hood to see how netbeans links the source to the library. I will be surprised if they do not have a human readable xml file somewhere.